# Ansible ad-hoc inventory not working when executed in a shell command in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Ansible v2.11.x

I have a Jenkins pipeline that does this. All the `$VARIABLES` are passed-in from the job's parameters.

```
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "VAULT_PASSWORD", variable: "VAULT_PASSWORD")]) {
    stage("Configure $env.IP_ADDRESS") {
      sh """
        ansible-playbook -i \\"$env.IP_ADDRESS,\\" \
                         -e var_host=$env.IP_ADDRESS \
                         -e web_branch=$env.WEB_BRANCH \
                         -e web_version=$env.WEB_VERSION \
                         site.yml
      """
    }
  }
```

My playbook is this

```
---
- hosts: "{{ var_host | default('site') }}"

  roles:
     - some_role
```

I have a `groups_vars/all.yml` file meant to be used by ad-hoc inventories like this. When I run the pipeline, I simply get the following, and the run does nothing

```
22:52:29  + ansible-playbook -i "10.x.x.x," -e var_host=10.x.x.x -e web_branch=development -e web_version=81cdedd6fe-20210811_2031 site.yml
22:52:31  [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 10.x.x.x
```

If I go on the build node and execute exactly the same command, it works. I can also execute the same command on my Mac, and it works too.

So why does the ad-hoc inventory not work when executed in the pipeline?

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in your `-i` argument where a comma is included in the string. You may also be having escape issues, and I do not believe you need to inner-interpolate your variable, and can pass the Groovy interpolated variable as a literal string to `ansible-playbook`. You may also want to try the Ansible Jenkins Pipeline plugin, as that works very well and could make this a lot easier.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, no that's the correct syntax for ad-hoc inventory list, with a `,` at the end. Like I said, the same exact command works when I execute it outside a pipeline. The variables are interpolated correctly too, I mean, it outputs the correct command. But I do agree, Jenkins doesn't like some syntax, it's just not obvious since it doesn't show me. I'm using a Jenkinsfile since I'm doing something else inside it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://gist.github.com/alces/f7e3de25d98a19550a4e4f97cabc2cf4) gave me a clue

The correct syntax that worked for me is

```
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "VAULT_PASSWORD", variable: "VAULT_PASSWORD")]) {
    stage("Configure $env.IP_ADDRESS") {
      sh """
        ansible-playbook -i $env.IP_ADDRESS, \
                         -e var_host=$env.IP_ADDRESS \
                         -e web_branch=$env.WEB_BRANCH \
                         -e web_version=$env.WEB_VERSION \
                         site.yml
      """
    }
  }
```